# Counting the Total Lines of Changes in a GitHub pull request(i.e. between two branches)

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is there a way to count the total number of change that appears in a pull request ? I wanted to build a tool that should restrict the users to commit, if the PR Lines of Change is more than a certian threshold.

I tried doing `git diff origin/master..<featureBranch>` but it's giving some incorrect lines of change. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [dangerJs](https://danger.systems/js/) seems an effective way to do the PR checks. I was actually looking for this kind of PR builder check:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/dangerfile.js#L17-L22

```
// Warn when PR size is large
var bigPRThreshold = 600;
if (danger.github.pr.additions + danger.github.pr.deletions > bigPRThreshold) {
  warn(':exclamation: Big PR (' + ++errorCount + ')');
  markdown('> (' + errorCount + ') : Pull Request size seems relatively large. If Pull Request contains multiple changes, split each into separate PR will helps faster, easier review.');
}
```

Comment: Link broken… any idea where it went?

Answer (score 3):

For counting changed lines of code in pull request you should use

```
git log --shortstat sha_of_commit
```

or

```
git log --stat sha_of_commit (more verbose output)
```

or if you have some diff, not commit, then you should swap diff with log:

```
git diff --stat / --shortstat
```

Comment: As a sidenote, `--numstat` might be handier for scripting purposes.

Comment: This assumes the PR consists of a single commit?

Comment: @PetrusTheron I think the thought is that once you merge the PR, that merge commit will have all of the changes in it.

Comment: `git log --shortstat sha_of_commit sha_of_commit~1`
worked for me